# What happens when I call a view in MySQL with a WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two questions:

Firstly, If I have a simple view in MySQL as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW `peopleView` AS
SELECT id, name, surname FROM people
```

And then I execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM peopleView WHERE id = 5
```

Does MySQL server create something like this in the background?

```
SELECT id, name, surname FROM people WHERE id = 5
```

In other words, it doesn't first execute the view, which maybe returns 5000 records, and then on those 5000 records it tries to filter to WHERE id = 5? This would make the view really slow...

Secondly, I believe views don't have indexes. So even if `surname` was indexed, and I execute

```
SELECT * FROM peopleView WHERE surname = 'Smith'
```

Would the query still have to traverse every single record to find all the 'Smiths', even though `Surname` is indexed, because the view loses all indexes?
Is it the same with primary keys? If `id` is a primary key, would

```
SELECT * FROM peopleView WHERE id = 563
```

have to traverse all records even though `id` is a primary key and indexed, because indexes are lost in views?

Thanks

Comment: Did you watch the execution plan for each query?

Comment: Views in MySQL are a waste of time.

Comment: @Strawberry Not always. Sometimes they help wrangle an ugly legacy schema into a form that's usable by normal people.

Comment: @tadman Ugly legacy schemas are a waste of time too! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How it handles it internally depends on a variety of factors, some documented, some mysterious, but in effect a `VIEW` acts like a macro. Views generally don't have indexes, but they can make use of indexes on their respective tables.

If/when MySQL supports "materialized views", which are like pre-computed views, this changes considerably.

Some platforms actually allow you to `INSERT` into a `VIEW` if the resulting statement would make sense.

Remember that `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` can tell you how MySQL understands your query and shows you what it's going to do to run it.

Comment: OK I tried the EXPLAIN. It seems like it does indeed use the index, if I understand correctly.

Comment: I.e. If I do a WHERE surname = 'Smith' on the view, and `surname` is indexed in the `people` table, the result of the EXPLAIN contains "key = surname_idx" which I guess means it's used?

Comment: You could experiment with performance on both indexed and non-indexed versions to see how this plays out.